# Django: How can I override unique validators error message?

Tags: django, authentication, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a custom user model class

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, BaseUserManager

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin)
    ...
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True) # Full name
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
```

And related view

```
class CustomUserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    pagination_class = BasePagination
    queryset = CustomUser.objects.all()
    ...

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = CustomUserSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.save()
            if user:
                json = serializer.data
                send_invitation_email(
                    user=user,
                    email=json["email"],
                    password=request.data["password"],
                    phone=json["phone_number"]
                )
                create_chats(user)
                return Response(json, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

In case of email, username duplicate I have the following error message:

> {"user_name":["custom user с таким user name уже существует."]}

How can I override error this message with my custom message:

> {"user_name":["Пользоватль с таким именем уже существует."]}

**UPDATE**
I updated my serializer

```
class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    avatar = serializers.FileField(use_url=False, required=False)
    organization = OrganizationSimpleSerializer(required=False, read_only=True)
    user_type = DepartmentSerializer(required=False, read_only=True)

    organization_id = serializers.IntegerField(required=True, write_only=True)
    user_type_id = serializers.IntegerField(required=True, write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = [
            ...
        ]
        read_only_fields = ("id",)
        extra_kwargs = {}
        extra_kwargs = {
            "password": {"write_only": True},
            "user_name": {
                "error_messages": {"unique": "Пользоватль с таким именем уже существует."}
            },
            "email": {
                "error_messages": {"unique": "Пользоватль с такой электронной почтой уже существует"}
            },
            "phone_number": {
                "error_messages": {"unique": "Пользоватль с таким телефоном уже существует"}
            }
        }
```

But I don't see my error message, I see this:

```
{"user_name":["Пользователь с таким user name уже существует."],"phone_number":["Пользователь с таким phone number уже существует."]}
```

It looks like check on the serializer level isn't working

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33268601/django-custom-authentication-login-how-to-display-error-message-when-authentic

Comment: I read this answer, but the answer is about login form, 
How can I apply this answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add your message in your validator in serialzier like this

so in `CustomUserSerializer` put this code :

```py
def validate_username(self,value):
   if your_logic:
      return value
   raise serializers.ValidationError('Пользоватль с таким именем уже существует.')
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution you can try.

```py
from rest_framework.validators import UniqueValidator


class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_name = serializers.CharField(validators=[
        UniqueValidator(
            queryset=CustomUser.objects.all(),
            message="Пользоватль с таким именем уже существует."
        )
    ])

    user_name = serializers.EmailField(validators=[
        UniqueValidator(
            queryset=CustomUser.objects.all(),
            message="Your custom email unique message here. "
        )
    ])
    # and so on... for your other fields with unique=True

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser  # your custom user model
        fields = '__all__'  # your fields here
```

Here is the rest-framework [validators docs link.](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#uniquevalidator)
Or you can override the default errors messages in your `model.py` too:

```py
class CustomUser(models.Model):
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True, error_messages={
        "unique": "Пользоватль с таким именем уже существует."
    })
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=128, unique=True, error_messages={
        "unique": "Your custom error message"
    })

    #...
```

Here is the [django doc link.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#error-messages)

#### Note: Already proposed solutions that isn't working for `unique=True` validator but will work for overriding other validation messages.

You can override the default error messages in your serializers by giving some `extra_kwargs` or even by adding a custom error message in your serializer field.

```py
# by using extra_kwargs

class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # ...
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser # your custom user model
        fields = '__all__' # your fields here
        extra_kwargs = {
            "user_name": {
                "error_messages": {"unique": "Пользоватль с таким именем уже существует."}
            },
            # you can do this same for your email field
            "email": {
                "error_messages": {"unique": "Your custom email unique message here. "}
            }
        }
```

Here is the adding custom message to the field explicitly.

```py
class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_name = serializers.CharField(
        error_messages={"unique": "Пользоватль с таким именем уже существует."}
    )
    email = serializers.EmailField(
        error_messages={"unique": "Your custom email unique message here. "}
    )
    
   # ...
```

But I personally prefer to customize the error message using the first method by providing the extra_kwargs.

Comment: Thank you, I was trying the first way, but i receive invalid response
``` {"email":["Пользователь с таким адрес электронной почты уже существует."],"user_name":["Пользователь с таким user name уже существует."],"phone_number":["Пользователь с таким phone number уже существует."]}```

Comment: @mascai I updated the answer. Have a look at that.